# How can I stop spacemacs from yanking to the MacOS clipboard?

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I'm using Spacemacs on MacOS with the GUI emacs with evil mode.

Yanking and deleting in Emacs overwrites the system clipboard.

How do I stop this? I want to keep the clipboards separate.

Comment: FWIW, in Emacs "yank" means paste, unlike in vim where it means cut.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. "yank" means "copy" in Vim. I wasn't sure how to ask this question, since I'm using Spacemacs with Evil mode. What I'm looking for is how to **in general** never touch the Mac OS clipboard from Spacemacs.

Answer (score 1):

There is a duplicate of this question on emacs.stackexchange: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/38863/2001. It even specifically uses spacemacs, and the given answer is accepted, suggesting that it works.

Comment: thanks - I didn't know about emacs.stackexchange. Worked great.

Answer (score 0):

A Google search for "emacs system clipboard" yielded https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Clipboard.html, which recommends:

> To prevent kill and yank commands from accessing the clipboard, change the variable `select-enable-clipboard` to `nil`.

Have you tried this?

Comment: yes, it didn't work :(  I suspect this is a spacemacs thing